# Paper in Laptop Fan

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop

I was using my laptop when I noticed a piece of paper under the grate at the bottom of the laptop where the fan is. I tried to get the paper out, but accidentally got it sucked into the fan and can no longer see it. Should I be concerned? I'm worried it will catch on fire in the hardware.

Comment: You should disassemble the case and remove the paper

Comment: It will probably not catch fire, but it might restrict the airflow inside your laptop and cause it to overheat. It should be removed if possible.